# docker hangs on SIGINT when script traps EXIT

Tags: bash, docker

When I run a script in a docker container, and the script traps EXIT, and I send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, docker fails to stop the container.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY script.sh /
CMD ./script.sh
```

*script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
func() {
  echo "exit script"
}
trap func EXIT
echo "script"
sleep 30
```

*To run*

```
$ docker build -t traps .
$ docker run -it traps
```

After seeing "script" echoed, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Expected: "exit script" is printed, and the container exits, returning control to my terminal, the same as if there were no EXIT trap.

Actual: "exit script" is printed, but the container is still running and holding onto my terminal.

To complicate matters, if I add a SIGINT trap, things work exactly as I would expect. On hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the SIGINT trap fires first, then the EXIT trap, and then the container exits.

What's going on? And is there any way to make things work without adding a dummy SIGINT trap?

(The reason for using `-t` in the first place is to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.)

Answer (score 2):

I ran your files and determined that bash entered a 100% CPU state after hitting Ctrl-C. Attaching gdb or strace indicates that it's SIGSEGVing infinitely.
If that is the case, you may be able to work around this by changing the shebang to:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

Or alternatively, the CMD command to:

```
CMD /bin/bash -i ./script.sh
```

Maybe look at this for more information: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4854

Comment: Upvoted for the great info. The linked issue does look relevant. But I'm hoping for an answer to "What's going on?" Reading that issue, pnasrat seems to know what's going on, and it's something to do with that jobs.c. But I couldn't connect the dots :)

Comment: I'm getting the bug on alpine (currently w/ bash 4.4.19(1)), centos (slightly older image, has bash 4.2.46(2)), but not on debian (bash 4.4.12(1)). The fact that alpine has a newer version than my image of debian is a bit annoying. Maybe Debian applied a patch that fixes this? Or maybe it's in a library somewhere.

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 14 image.